# If we define "good" as "giving satisfaction" who is getting satisfaction in a sentence like "the book was good"?

Tags: meaning

> [good](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/good?s=t) - satisfactory in quality, quantity, or degree
>
> [satisfactory](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/satisfactory) - giving or affording satisfaction; fulfilling all demands or requirements

How would we reword a sentence like "the book was good" to fit this definition? "The book was giving satisfaction to me (the speaker)" doesn't seem to fit because that sentence is a fact, and "the book was good" is an opinion. "The book was giving satisfaction to people in general" still seems like a fact as well.

Comment: I found the book to be satisfying.

Comment: The question is loaded. Let's use [AHDEL](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/good)'s definition here instead:
a. [i] Superior to the average ... a good student. You still need to ask how students, books etc are rated – but it now becomes obvious that the question is about education or literary criticism etc, not about the use of words.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks that we use a non-optimal definition.

Comment: Many linguists think that good can't be defined, that it is a semantic prime.

Answer (score 2):

Alas, things are not that simple.  The *OED* give 23 major senses of the meaning of the adjective *good*.  I didn't bother to count the subcategories.  All of them speak to a positive valuation on some scale, and satisfaction is but one of these.  A reviewer and a bookworm beetle will differ about what it is that's good about a book; when an atheist and a Christian may both refer to the Good Book (although the former may be doing so ironically), it's unlikely both will take satisfaction from it.  Context is everything, and that can't be captured in one subheading in a word's dictionary definition.

Comment: To amplify slightly, (and justify my upvote) a second hand bookseller might refer to a book as "good" if it is easily sellable. You might call a book good if it covers its subject matter adequately regardless of any satisfaction it might give you. You can also call a book good if you think it is likely to give satisfaction to the reader or if it gave you satisfaction when you read it.

Comment: Another driveby downvoter, a curse upon this site.  If you don't have the common courtesy to explain yourself to the answerer, consider that you may leave the impression that correct answers are wrong or leave no avenue for improvement of incorrect answers.